# Chrome extension 'No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin' api call hits server but returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors

I have a simple ajax request to my local server running on ngrok. The AJAX call is able to hit the server, however the browser stops the response with the following error

```
Failed to load https://8ee2ec1.ngrok.io/my_endpoint: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://cahhljhlafgalbkdajphjklmameocbba' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I fix this? I would have thought if this was a CORS issue the api request would not have made it to the server, but it does.

```
// request

  var params = {
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://8ee2ec1.ngrok.io/my_endpoint",
  }
  $.ajax(params).done(function(resp) { console.log(resp) }
  })
```

Manifest

```
{
  "permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "notifications", "webRequest", "tabs"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm added the manifest, thanks for your patience

Comment: take a look here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

It *is* a CORS issue. You need to add an [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) (among other CORS headers) to your end point's response, as the error suggests. It's as simple as that.

Here's [MDN's take on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), for reference.

It reaches the server as an HTTP request under the `OPTIONS` method. That's how CORS requests work; they have to reach the server to be able to read your headers. After the `OPTIONS` request is responded to by your server with the appropriate CORS headers it sends another under the method specified in your client-side code.